# Adding new column customer_id in Magento Customer Grid no index values

Tags: magento

Adding new column `customer_id` in Magento Customer Grid no index values.

I have problem adding new column `customer_id` in my Magento Customer grid which results no index values. The column is empty.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
   public function __construct()
    {
     parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customerGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }   

 protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')        
        ->addNameToSelect()             
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')  
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')           
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {      
         $this->addColumn('customer_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'customer_id',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));
   /*more columns*/
   return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }  }
```

---

I think the problem is in `_prepareCollection()`. This `customer_id` resides from another table and not exist in the default Customer grid table. Please help, I'm trying playing for 8hours but unable to solve.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the grid?

Comment: why you had added `customer_id` into another table?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned that you had override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` or not, as you had putted the code from `core/Mage`.

But if you are gonna override it then I would suggest you not to override the `_prepareCollection()` instead override the method `setCollection()` as:

```
public function setCollection($collection) {
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id'); //although this may not add that column for you.
// you need to join the collection with your table in order to do that
    $this->_collection = $collection;
}
```

then add your column to grid as:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumnAfter('customer_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer ID'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'customer_id'
    ), 'entity_id');
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```